# Custom phone number validation add for all phone number fields present in the site in magento 2.1.4

Tags: magento2

**Could not find the proper filenames and process of adding the validation code.**  *I am trying to add a validation for phone number field i.e check for all-numbers and also is it correct according to the country code or not.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**step1) Add the following in vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="testPhone" xsi:type="string">true</item>
  </item>
</item>
```

**step2) Add the following in vendor\magento\magento2-base\lib\web\mage\validation.js**

```
"testPhone": [
    function (phone_number, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/([+]?\d{1,2}[.-\s]?)?(\d{3}[.-]?){2}\d{4}/g) &&
        phone_number.match(/^[-+]?[0-9]+$/);
    },
        'Please specify a valid mobile number'
  ],
```

**step3) Add the following in vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\lib\validation\rules.js**

```
"testPhone": [
            function(value) {
                return value.length > 9 && value.match(/([+]?\d{1,2}[.-\s]?)?(\d{3}[.-]?){2}\d{4}/g) && value.match(/^[-+]?[0-9]+$/);
            },
            $.mage.__('Please specify a valid mobile number')
        ],
```

Comment: Down voted. Updating core framework files is bad practice, for the simplest reason: when you update your framework version, your changes go away.

Comment: Please rewrite your answer with custom files.

Comment: totally agree with @MiguelFelipeGuillenCalo  we should never modify the core files and changes should be done through custom module.
Thanks